# Generate HTTP response in java proxy server

Tags: java, http, proxy, response

How would I display an HTTP 403 response to the client when the client attempts to access a forbidden page? I have the code below, but it doesn't display anything on the clients browser. May be a trivial error, but I'm new to this so anything helps.

```
                            // If webpage is not allowed, then redirect user to a blocked
            // URL page
            if (!checkHost(fin, requestSplit[3].split("\r")[0])) {
                System.out.println("DON'T SHOW");

                OutputStream to_client = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
                PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(to_client);
                ps.print("HTTP/1.1  403 Forbidden\r\n");
                ps.print("Connection: close\r\n");
                ps.print("\r\n");
                ps.close();
```

Comment: What's the problem? Just send back a valid HTTP 403 response. The syntax is trivial, and examples abound.

Comment: Your edit is still wrong. Try again with the line terminators.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should close the `PrintStream,` not the `Socket.`
2. The line terminator in HTTP is defined as `\r\n`, not whatever `println()` does, which is platform-dependent.
3. There's no point in setting a `Content-type`, a `Date`, or an `Accept-Ranges` header in a 404 response.
4. `incomingOS` is a terrible name for an output stream.

Your edit doesn't comply with (2) above.